# ADT: fail to build when there are too many packages and classes

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a big project with many library projects as well as many packages and classes in source code.

Using ADT (r20) in Eclipse (v4.2) to build, I get this error:

> [2012-07-08 09:05:33 - AndroidUIPatterns] Dx  trouble writing output:
> Too many fields: 69379; max is 65536. By package:
>
> ```
> 19 android.app
> 14 android.content.pm
>  5 android.content.res
>  2 android.gesture
> 39 android.graphics
>  8 android.graphics.drawable
> 13 android.os
>  3 android.provider
> ```
>
> ...
> ...
> [2012-07-08 09:05:33 - AndroidUIPatterns] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2

For full error log, your can see it here: http://pastie.org/4218297

It seems there is a maximum limit for number of package / class in an Android project?

I'll appreciate all your help if anyone can tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: According to log you have tried to build android sources - why do you need this?

Comment: Hey, did you try using the progurad to remove the files which are not used ? And optimize the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a limitation of dx compiler that is currently limited to 65536 (2^16) field/method references per dex. It's "being fixed" since 2010.

The only solution now is to split application into multiple dex files, so no single dex file exceeds the 64k limit.

Comment: I would be very please if you can tell me how to split app into multile dex files.

Comment: Info (including an example) from Android Developers blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: Seems SDK r21 has "really fixed" this bug.