# Can we create multi dex support builds in Titanium android?

Tags: android, titanium

I have been developing an application in Titanium android.Somehow after updating titanium i started getting the 65k limit error and the solution i got is :
https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/
But how to implement these in Titanium ?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this @ajit

Comment: I guess, titanium gonna support multidex methods soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question was asked and an issue was created in 2014:  https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18082

however, it is not resolved.  (Under Titanium SDK 5.1.1.GA)

I met this problem today, and my solution is:

*remove the unnecessary jar files*!

Those jar files was referred by some java class, has huge methods ( more than 1k) but it will not be used at run time, so removing them will not cause app crash nor throw exceptions.

This is not an final solution, but kinda of trick. whatever, it works for me.